# Laravel - Migrate database from other frameworks

Tags: database, laravel, codeigniter, migration, data-migration

I was working on a project which is already advanced, specially the database, that has been filled by someone from my team, even though part of it has not been used yet. Some tables can be emptied and refilled as it's sample data, however most of them contains data which will be actually used or it's been used in the parts we're doing now.

The project started in CodeIgniter, by we've realized that Laravel can save us hours of work, so we're planning to migrate it. The point is that we didn't use the CodeIgniter's migration system, and we've seen in the Laravel documentation that only the table structure will be migrated, plus we have to create every migration.

The question here is if there's a way to both, create the migratinos files automatically, and to keep the relevant data that will be used in the application so we don't need to refill the database again (yep, there are kind of big tables). We thought on the seeders, but what we've seen is that they only store sample data...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel migration generator. It will simply help you to generate migrations from your 
 existing database. Check it out below. You will find in readme how to use it. Good luck.

https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator

Hope , it helps. Thanks. Cheers. -_-

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I installed the module and tried to migrate as the documentation says, however I had the same result: tables are empty. Also, I had problems with the default Laravel's migrations: "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))" . Using Laravel 5.5.40